# add accessibility custom slider iOS

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I have a custom slider that changes value based on `super.beginTrackingWithTouch` and `super.continueTrackingWithTouch`. It follows a quadratic path.

Looking to make the custom slider accessible. Any ideas on how to do it?

I was thinking of adding a standard iOS slider, adding accessibilityLabel, and passing those values to the custom slider. Having trouble making the standard slider functional but invisible to the user though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's generally best practice to extend a standard control to perform the special behavior you need. As author of a completely custom control, you're responsible for more of its accessibility.

Experiment with a `UISlider` using VoiceOver on your device. See how it behaves. You want to maintain as much of this experience as possible as you implement your own control. You can use [Accessibility Inspector in Simulator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/TestingAccessibilityOfiOSApps/TestAccessibilityiniOSSimulatorwithAccessibilityInspector/TestAccessibilityiniOSSimulatorwithAccessibilityInspector.html) to explore system controls' accessibility configurations.

The following steps are almost certainly relevant:

1. Override or set `- (BOOL)isAccessibilityElement` to return `YES`.
2. Override or set `- (CGRect)accessibilityFrame` to return an appropriate rectangle in screen coordinates.
3. Override or set `- (UIAccessibilityTraits)accessibilityTraits` to include `UIAccessibilityTraitAdjustable`.
4. Override `- (NSString *)accessibilityValue` to describe the current value of your control.
5. Implement `- (void)accessibilityIncrement` and `- (void)accessibilityDecrement` to perform value changes requested by assistive clients such as VoiceOver.

Beyond the steps above, I can't say what's required for your specific control without more details. If you get stuck, review the [Accessibility Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Introduction/Introduction.html), [UIAccessibility Protocol documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibility_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008786), and [UIAction protocol documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibilityAction_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009678), and return to StackOverflow with any questions that remain.

Best luck and thank you for giving this the attention it deserves.

Answer (score -1):

If accessible you mean voice over you can do the following pretending mySlider is the name to your Slider Control:

```
    [mySlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

- (IBAction)sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    NSString *valueToAnnounce=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"slider value = %f", sender.value];
    UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityAnnouncementNotification, valueToAnnounce);
}
```

This Blog has helped me multiple times with Voice Over questions:
http://www.podfeet.com/blog/tutorials-5/build-accessible-ios-apps/

Comment: I'll have to return to provide a better answer, but just posting an announcement when the value changes is the wrong approach. It won't behave like other sliders, doesn't improve accessibility for users of other assistive technologies like Switch Control, and may be incomprehensible to VoiceOver users.